# vsts extensions + build-results-enhance

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

when trying to upload am getting below error
Error:
(Build Results Enhancer) This extension targets Visual Studio 2017 but was not built with an up-to-date VSSDK. Please make sure to update your references and try uploading again. Note: you'll also need to add Prerequisites to your extension.vsixmanifest.
(Build Results Enhancer) This package has an Installation element that includes an InstallationTarget for Visual Studio 2010 which does not support this version of the VSIX schema.
(Build Results Enhancer) This extension targets Visual Studio 2017 but was not built with an up-to-date VSSDK. Please make sure to update your references and try uploading again. Note: you'll also need to add Prerequisites to your extension.vsixmanifest.
Publisher display name (PadmaPeddigari) in Marketplace and Author name (fabrikam) in the extension need to be the same to publish the extension.

Comment: Please try to follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017) to migrate your project. Also, please install these nuget packages `Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools 15.9.xxxx` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK 15.0.xxx `.

Comment: Also, you should add` Prerequisites` in  `extension.vsixmanifest` file from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ms-my/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017#make-changes-to-the-vsix-extension-manifest).

Answer (score 0):

> vsts extensions + build-results-enhance

Before you upload your project, you should upgrade your old vsix project.

**Step**

**1)** open your project in VS2017 and then install this nuget package [Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools/) version `15.9.xxx` and [Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK/16.0.205?_src=template) version `15.0.1`.

Or if you already have the nuget pakages, you could update it to `15.xxx` version.

**2)** open `source.extension.vsixmanifest` file and click **view code**, and then make sure you have Prerequisite xml node and make sure that these related nodes include `15.0`.

For an example, set **Version** of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor` to `[xxx,15.0]` or `[xxx,16.0)`.

**Besides**, more detailed steps, you could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017).

Any feedback will be expected.